# Surface integral of second kind

Tags: real-analysis

Find the flow of the vector field $\overrightarrow{V}=x \overrightarrow{i}+y\overrightarrow{j}+z\overrightarrow{k}$ through the side surface of the cylinder $x^2+y^2=a^2$, $0 \le z \le H$. ($a,H > 0$)

Well, $\nabla F=(2x,2y,0)$, where $F=x^2+y^2-a$. Then $|| \nabla F ||=2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, and $\overrightarrow{n} = \left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},0 \right)$.

So,
$$ \iint\limits_S x dydz+ydxdz+zdxdy = \iint\limits_{S} \sqrt{x^2+y^2} d \sigma . $$
But now I'm stucked, because I can't write z in function of x and y. Can anybody help me, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $\int_S\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\>{\rm d}\sigma$ is fine. Now note that on $S$ one has $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}= a$; furthermore $\int_S{\rm d}\sigma=2\pi a H$, by elementary geometry. Therefore the flow in question is $2\pi a^2 H$.

Comment: Ok! Thank you! But how could I continue if I had $\iint _S x d \sigma$ ?

Comment: One has ${\rm d}\sigma=a{\rm d}(\phi,z)$ and $x=a\cos\phi$. Therefore $$\int_S x\>{\rm d}\sigma=\int_0^H\int_0^{2\pi} a\cos\phi\>d\phi\>dz=0\ .$$